# concurrent git pull and push on same remote repo from different locations

Tags: git

Suppose I'm pulling or cloning from some remote git repo
What happens if
1) after I started pulling/cloning - someone start to push to that remote repo in the middle?
2) while someone is in the middle of pushing code to remote git repo - and I start pulling cloning it?

What do I end up with in each of the cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem in either case.  In case 1) there'll be a point when the ref (a branch name, typically) is updated when someone's pushing, and any fetch (an essential part of clone and pull) will either get the old value before that point or the new one afterwards.  The ref is only updated when all the objects required for it are in the remote repository's object database, so there's no problem there. 2)  Similarly, if the fetch that makes up your pull happens after the ref that's being pushed to is updated, then you'll get the new value, otherwise you'll get the old one.

(One possible exception to this is the "dumb HTTP" transport, where you need to run `git update-server-info` in the remote repository after each push, so it's possible that a fetch will fail immmediately after a push but before the hook runs that command - however, it's relatively rare to use the dumb HTTP transport nowadays, I think.)