# Are concurrent operations possible with Git repositories?

Tags: git

There are two scenarios that I'm interested in.

- The repository is shared and two users want to push changes to it at the same time
- I want to schedule a nightly or weekly "gc" using a cron job. It runs and someone wants to push or clone during the operation.

Is there a risk of corruption in either of these scenarios?

Comment: For #1, I'm assuming you're talking about concurrent pushes to different branches? Concurrent pushes to the same branch is answered elsewhere on SO.

Comment: [q8424232](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424232/are-concurrent-git-pushes-always-safe-if-the-second-push-only-has-fast-forwards); [q6028141](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028141/concurrent-git-pull-and-push-on-same-remote-repo-from-different-locations) might be interesting too.

Answer (score 12):

Git allows concurrent operations by using a [Pessimistic Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Concurrency_control_mechanisms).

When necessary, git creates some special files to act as locks.

In particular, every time the index is modified by an operation, git creates a file called `index.lock` in the `.git` directory to lock the shared resource. Git creates at needs other lock files: for example, a `.keep` file is created during [git index-pack](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-index-pack) operations.

In general, you shouldn't worry about concurrent operations with git: it is carefully designed to support them.

Someone could tell you shouldn't worry about performing `gc` with a cron job, since git itself triggers `gc` from time to time. Even if this is true, the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) itself recommends:

```
Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis 
within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization
and good operating performance.
```

Hence, I think it's not a bad idea to schedule a job task to run git's garbage collection. I just wonder if it is a premature optimisation or if you are trying to solve a real, measured issue. I personally haven't ever had problems that required me to manually run `gc`, but I wouldn't be surprised if your case is pretty different.

Answer (score 4):

In general, "`git gc`" may delete objects that another concurrent process
is using but hasn't created a reference to.
Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) has more on this.

See [commit f1350d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1350d0c125a1e6a73e3b6461fa90c77843c5f74) (15 Nov 2016) by [Matt McCutchen (`mattmccutchen`)](https://github.com/mattmccutchen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 979b82f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/979b82f19f3c44d34779c46c636aade514a711a9), 10 Jan 2017)</sup>

And see [Jeff King's comment](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=147922960131779&w=2):

> Modern versions of git do two things to help with this:
>
> - any object which is referenced by a "recent" object (within the 2
>     weeks) is also considered recent. So if you create a new commit
>     object that points to a tree, even before you reference the commit
>     that tree is protected
> - when an object write is optimized out because we already have the
>     object, git will update the mtime on the file (loose object or
>     packfile) to freshen it
>
> This isn't perfect, though. You can decide to reference an existing
>   object just as it is being deleted. And the pruning process itself is
>   not atomic (and it's tricky to make it so, just because of what we're
>   promised by the filesystem).
>
> If you have long-running data (like, a temporary index file that might
>   literally sit around for days or weeks) I think that is a potential
>   problem. And the solution is probably to use refs in some way to point
>   to your objects.
>   If you're worried about a short-term operation where
>   somebody happens to run `git-gc` concurrently, I agree it's a possible
>   problem, but I suspect something you can ignore in practice.
>
> For a busy multi-user server, I recommend turning off auto-gc entirely,
>   and repacking manually with "`-k`" to be on the safe side.

This is why [`git gc` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1350d0c125a1e6a73e3b6461fa90c77843c5f74/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L137-L168) now includes:

> On the other hand, when '`git gc`' runs concurrently with another process,
>   there is a risk of it deleting an object that the other process is using
>   but hasn't created a reference to. This may just cause the other process
>   to fail or may corrupt the repository if the other process later adds a
>   reference to the deleted object.
>
> Git has two features that significantly mitigate this problem:
>
> - Any object with modification time newer than the `--prune` date is kept,
>     along with everything reachable from it.
> - Most operations that add an object to the database update the
>     modification time of the object if it is already present so that #1
>     applies.
>
> However, these features fall short of a complete solution, so users who
>   run commands concurrently have to live with some risk of corruption (which
>   seems to be low in practice) unless they turn off automatic garbage
>   collection with 'git config gc.auto 0'.

---

Note on that last sentence including "unless they turn off automatic garbage": Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) amend the gc documentation.

See [commit 0044f77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0044f7700fdbfdb04b8f88c385ca6fd545e1e1bb), [commit daecbf2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daecbf2261f595935c999a00a1f9bc433df80e2c), [commit 7384504](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73845048815bace98588df03ab76fa3e85fc0927), [commit 22d4e3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22d4e3bd19bc81b3db6f372d850ad681333a7fb1), [commit 080a448](https://github.com/git/git/commit/080a4480a07ae9831bf2685564641f6e5530cf87), [commit 54d56f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54d56f52bdf477b6167cc8f97f8afb5b78eb39fa), [commit d257e0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d257e0fb0adc1eefa8e237391cd0e3aaa9d69e9d), [commit b6a8d09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6a8d09f6d85693dad19bbcfd2b18f9e6fc81ee4) (07 Apr 2019), and [commit fc559fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc559fbb54e5852be7d9cbd854a375333409aa2f), [commit cf9cd77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf9cd771e1314ad5cd8eaf1d92b7a5fd5e6b734f), [commit b11e856](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b11e8560cc1be17268136504cb80b00fbf4182dc) (22 Mar 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ac70c53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac70c5313351630e44b1fe0267fb4850ebcf1f25), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `gc` docs: remove incorrect reference to `gc.auto=0`
>
> The chance of a repository being corrupted due to a "`gc`" has nothing
>   to do with whether or not that "gc" was invoked via "`gc --auto`", but
>   whether there's other concurrent operations happening.
>
> This is already noted earlier in the paragraph, so there's no reason to suggest this here. The user can infer from the rest of the documentation that "`gc`" will run automatically unless `gc.auto=0` is set, and we shouldn't confuse the issue by implying that "`gc --auto`" is somehow more prone to produce corruption than a normal "`gc`".
>
> Well, it is in the sense that a blocking "`gc`" would stop you from
>   doing anything else in *that* particular terminal window, but users
>   are likely to have another window, or to be worried about how
>   concurrent "`gc`" on a server might cause corruption.