# How to work inside a repository while Git Shell is in the middle of pushing?

Tags: github

If I'm in the middle of pushing a repository through Git Shell where it says something like:

- Counting objects: 1336, done.
- Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
- Compressing objects: 100% (1327/1327), done.
- Writing objects:  10% (144/1336), 101.58 MiB | 1.19 MiB/s

Can I still work inside that folder or should I wait until it's done? 
(This is just locally, not involving other users. I probably should wait but it's taking so long!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13039150/2557145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are concurrent operations possible with Git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039150/are-concurrent-operations-possible-with-git-repositories)